# Can the SQL credentials packet ever be in an unencrypted state?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I understand that SQL credentials packet is always encrypted, even in the absence of SSL.

However when I research about this I'm findings the following examples when the credentials packet may be unencrypted. Are the following cases true for SQL server?

1. Negotiation Process: During the initial connection handshake, both client and server negotiate encryption capabilities. If neither side requires encryption, the entire connection, including the login packet, remains unencrypted. This scenario is uncommon but possible, especially in legacy setups or insecure environments.
2. Client or Driver Limitations: Even if the server enforces encryption, if the client application or driver lacks encryption support, the credentials might be sent in plain text. This typically occurs with outdated or non-standard clients.

Or can we safely always assume the the credentials packet is always encrypted by SQL server?